# IONIC 2:Why I'm getting an error 12501 for google login integration in IONIC 2?

Tags: android, angular, ionic2, google-plus, hybrid-mobile-app

I am getting an error 12501 in IONIC 2 for google login integration.how can I solve this problem, Also tell me proper generation of Client ID on Google developer's API. Below is my google login code. check it and tell me whether the client ID is proper?
Thanks in Advance..

```
 doGoogleLogin(){
            let nav = this.navCtrl;
            let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
              content: 'Please wait...'
            });
            loading.present();
              GooglePlus.login({
                'scopes': '',
                'webClientId': '1039283685376-ub138v89t4dm322m9a5kttab0uq0d03t.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                'offline': true
            }).then(res=>alert(res))
            .catch(err=>alert(err)) 
          }
```

Comment: checkout the two answers of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718350/12501-error-ionic-what-keystore-is-the-app-building-with/