# 12501 error: Ionic what keystore is the app building with

Tags: cordova, ionic2, firebase-authentication, android-keystore, google-plus-signin

I am using `Ionic 2` with [GooglePlus Authentication](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-plus/). Everything works perfectly for `iOS`. For `Android` I build my app as follows:

```
ionic build android
```

For the `Android` build, I need a `SHA1` keystore for Google Authentication.

I have a `Macintosh HD/Users/myname/.android/debug.keystore`, so according to [these](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) instructions, I generate a keystore using (default password '`android`'):

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

The output looks correct. I use this `SHA1` to for my `Android Credentials` as per the above instructions:

[image]

But when I try login, I get: **`error = 12501`**

From [here](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/327) I believe it's related to not having the `SHA1` in the Google Credentials matching the `SHA1` for the Android build of the app.

**Question**

What `SHA1` is my `Android` build using? How do I check if it matches the one generated above for the credentials?

**UPDATE**

From reading the following:

[image]

I understand it, that for `Android`, we need to put the `SHA1` here:

[image]

However, after trying this, I still get the `12501` error.

**UPDATE**

I have also tried following [these instructions](http://docs.ionic.io/services/auth/google-native.html), specifically the `Android Setup`, but I think it's outdated. But they do say the following:

> If you get Error 12501 - User Cancelled, this means you used the wrong
>   Bundle ID during your iOS/Android configuration steps. Make sure you
>   are using the correct one, by setting your desired Bundle ID in your
>   config.xml, and using that ID during the Device Setup

As you can see from the image above, the `Package name` matches the `Bundle ID` in `config.xml`.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.thewhozooXXXX" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Comment: If you are using the Google Sign-In Cordova/PhoneGap Plugin then you may need to read the section [before you proceed](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus#before-you-proceed) the author mentions that you may get `12501` error if you do not edit the package name in `config.xml`

Comment: Thanks.  I am away from my computer right now but will test later.  Question: if I have 2 credentials  (iOS & Android), which client ID do I use in the config.xml? I read that I should use the iOS one, because Android doesn't look at it. Is that correct?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, for hybrid apps (ios + android) you will actually only use _one_ client id, this will be the client id provided by google (from google dev console). You can read the ["IMPORTANT" section in the docs](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus#4-installation-phonegap-cli--cordova-cli) for more info on this.

Comment: When you talk about the `'package name'` in the `config.xml`, is that the `widget id`?  My `widget id` is equal to the `Package name` in the credential set up for the OAuth Client. Also this equals the `package` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Yeah, the widget id. If they are the same and you still have the problem, then I am not too sure what the issue is, I will be implementing this plugin in one of my apps this weekend and to be honest I am not looking forward to it, set up seems quite tedious. If I get it working, I can ping you here to let you know the steps.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. If I manage to fix the issue, I will put the answer here, it may help you if you have the same problem.

Comment: Great, thanks! Just saw on the docs as well - you need to add the Release  build certificate fingerprint to google console. That may be the cause of your issue if you are using the debug fingerprint

Comment: Do you need both a release and debug certificate?  I thought you could have one or the other?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137764/discussion-between-und3rtow-and-richard).

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION

You need to use a `Web Client ID` and not an `Android Client ID` for Android (Go Figure!). This worked for me.

[image]

code:

```
        GooglePlus.login({
            'webClientId':'XXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            'offline': true
        }).then(googleData => {
```

What I do not understand however, is that for `iOS` it works with the `iOS Client id`. So there's no consistency.

**UPDATE**

This seems to work for `Android` using the `Web client`. If you look at the return value `googleData`:

```
googleData.providerData[0].displayName 
googleData.providerData[0].photoUrl
```

Comment: The above seems to work for Android. But for iOS, I get the following issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42736623/google-firebase-authentication-no-displayname-or-photourl-for-ios

Answer (score 0):

For future references so it might help others like me:

My problem was the scope parameter:

```
{
    'scopes': 'email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.resource.calendar',
    'webClientId': 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    'offline': true
}
```

It is a **SPACE seperated list** (I used comma seperated). Comma seperation (or any other than space seperation) will result in 12501.